# MySQL SELECT not working when data in table

Tags: mysql

I am having an issue with a MySQL SELECT query.
Here is the data in the table
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcVSZ.jpg
This query doesn't, even though the data is in there
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guj0B.jpg
Does anyone know why this is happening? The data type is a float, and a similar variable works.

Comment: have you tried to put pos value in quotes?

Comment: Please, whenever possible post things like that as plain text formatted as code if necessary in the body of your question. External links like that are unreliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be the value stored is not exactly 0.7

```
try 

select * from learned_info where pos > 0.6;

or could be the value are not float
```

Comment: This did work for all cases. What was weird though is that I created these as strings, and put them into the database casted as floats. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ***pos<=0.7 AND pos LIKE '%0.7';***

Is it helping?